Trees sway in unison in Unreal Engine 5 with Megascans European Black Alder Pack
I’m experiencing a strange issue in my Unreal Engine project. The trees in my scene have started to animate unexpectedly, almost as if they are performing a synchronized "dance" or wave motion, similar to a Brazilian wave. While it's amusing to watch, it's obviously not the intended behavior.
Here are some details:

Tree Pack: I'm using the Megascans Trees: European Black Alder pack.
My Unreal Engine version is: 5.4.4
Issue: All the trees sway in unison with a wave-like motion
Research: After searching online, I found that a few other users have reported similar issues, but I couldn’t find a concrete solution.

As entertaining as it is to see, I’d like to fix it. Has anyone else encountered this problem or know what could be causing it?

What is the expected behaviour though, all trees waving random, or in waves or .. ?

It's only a simple wind movement or no moving at all. Those are trees, they shouldn't be dancing at all.

This has a possible answer here: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/megascan-trees-issue-with-procedural-foliage-spawners-ue5-1/726621/30

The primary purpose of each Stack Exchange site is to enable users to post questions and answer them. Users can vote on both answers and questions and through this process, users earn reputation points, a form of gamification.

Another reason is the difference from the forum sites. Historically we don't like forums, because it has been difficult to find answers. It is better to help the community by adding more questions and answers to collect information in one place.

No need to search other sites. Stack overflow puts something better than forum culture. What do you mean by saying "This has a possible answer here..". This is the place to find the answers. Try to help by adding content, not by trying to hinder.

Solution
I discovered that this issue is a known bug with the Megascans Trees: European Black Alder pack. After spending some time troubleshooting, I found a fix and wanted to share the steps with the community.
Follow these steps to resolve the issue:

In your Content Browser, select all items on the left, and in the search bar, type MF_SimpleWind



Open MF_SimpleWind

Look for the Main Rotator comment box within the material and locate it




Double-click on the ObjectPivotPoint to open it

Select Transform Position at the middle-top of the window




In the Source drop-down list at the details, choose Instance & Particle Space


This should fix the waving tree animation issue.
